# using SpListFilterWebPart in sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part, filter

I want to use SpListFilterWebPart in allitems.aspx view in my share point 2013 and I do it with share point designer 2013 but I can't see SpListFilterWebPart in my page view
Why it happened?

Comment: Why SharePoint Designer? Have you tried simply editting the page and adding the webpart there?

Comment: In /Lists/EmailAdressesList/Allitems.aspx how can I edit the page?

Comment: Top right, gear icon and then "Edit page".